# Optimizing DRF post request handling by preventing full response serialization back

Tags: python, django, rest, optimization, django-rest-framework

I have defined `AViewSet` and `ASerializer` for my `AModel`:

```
class AModel(Model):
    name = CharField(16)
    text = TextField()
    related = ForeignField('ARelated')

class AViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = AModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ASerializer

class ASerializer(Serializer):
    class Meta(object):
        model = AModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

I wrote a RESTful client that posts *a lot* of data to that view/endpoint in multiple requests, creating many `AModel` records. I have noticed, however that a significant part of the server time is spent on *generating the response*, and upon googling for a bit I found several references to the [nested relationship hazard](http://ses4j.github.io/2015/11/23/optimizing-slow-django-rest-framework-performance/) which seems like a decent fix, but got me wondering:

I already know what I posted and I don't need the `pk`s, so could I prevent that serialization response from happening entirely? Can I instead just serialize the number of rows inserted?

Taking a look at DRF's `CreateModelMixin` class:

```
class CreateModelMixin(object):
    """
    Create a model instance.
    """
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

I realized I could override the `create` method and reimplement it without returning the `serializer.data` as part of the response, so it'll look similar to this:

```
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response({}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

I have two questions regarding this approach:

1. Does this practice of preventing the full serialization of objects created with a POST makes sense wrt RESTful design patterns, approach, ideology, etc?
2. Will this actually avoid `select`ing all the related data (as well as execute any `SerializerMethodField`s, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the basic **`ModelViewset`** and **`ModelSerializer`** combination here :) It will be like,

```
# serializers.py
class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SampleModel
        fields = '__all__'

# views.py
class SampleViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SampleModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SampleSerializer
```

---

**Why DRF returning all the data back to client ?**
Here, the **`SampleViewset`** is using **`SampleSerializer`** everytime and it will serialilze ***all*** fields defined in the serializer class. As per the current configuration

**What is the possible solution?**
The possible solution is for this is stop serialization process of certain fields by some means :)

**How to do?**
As far as I knew, this can be done in *two* ways.
1. Use a minimal `SampleSerializer` class for `POST` method
2. override the **`to_representation()`** method of `SampleSerializer` on `POST` requests

**Method-1 : Use different serializer**
Define a new serializer class with fields which are you wish to ***send and retrive while `POST` request***

```
class SampleSerializerMinimal(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SampleModel
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'age')
```

Now, we've to tell viewsets to use this serializer for POST methods, it can be done in **`get_serializer_class()`** of viewset

```
class SampleViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SampleModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SampleSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return SampleSerializerMinimal
        return SampleSerializer
```

**Method-2 : Override the `to_representation()` method**

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SampleModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        try:
            if self.context['view'].request.method == 'POST':
                return {
                    "id": instance.id,
                    "name": instance.name,
                    "age": instance.age
                }
        except KeyError:
            return super(SampleSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        return super(SampleSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
```

**What is the best way ?**
I felt ***Method-1*** is more DRF way of doing things, but you can't add `id` only to the `fields` because, POST request may require more fields.
The ***`Method-2`*** to is also good, but its not much clean if you want to return `n` fields, and writing it in your `to_representation()` method

---

**UPDATE-1**
**Method-3: Combination of `method-1` and `method-2`**

```
# serializer.py
class SampleSerializerMinimal(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SampleModel
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'age')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        """
        we don't have to check the request method, because DRF routing only POSt requests to this serializer
        """
        return {"id": instance.id}


# views.py
class SampleViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SampleModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SampleSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action.method == 'POST':
            return SampleSerializerMinimal
        return SampleSerializer
```

---

**UPDATE-2**

> Does this practice of preventing the full serialization of objects created with a POST makes sense wrt RESTful design patterns, approach, ideology, etc?

the **`.data`** is calling **`to_representation()`** method, which calls the ***related objects and all other fields in the serializer***. ( [Source code of **`data`** property of serializer](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L249) ) So, if you can avoid that **`.data`** call, it would be nice!.
Since I've seen many API responses with single detail like **`{"status":true}`** after a POST request, I don't think your approch ***overkill the DRF patterns and other stuff***

> Will this actually avoid selecting all the related data (as well as execute any SerializerMethodFields, etc?

Yes. As I said above, It won't call the serializations process unless calling the **`.data`**

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! regarding Method 1 (which I find more elegant), won't this limit the *original post request* to those fields defined in `SampleSerializerMinimal` too, instead of just the *response*?

Comment: If I understand correctly, it confirmed my suspect. Right?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. But we could do apply `method-2` to `method-1` , (a combination of things)

Comment: @NirIzr I've updated the answer with a `Method-3`. Hope it help :)

Comment: Thanks! I've considerably modified my question to be clearer wrt the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: can you check the **`Update-2`** section ?